# useState() hook value 1 step behind, already using useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an list of values `pairList` that I'm trying to access with an `id` from the click event. There is a popup list that doesn't even display if `pairList` is not populated. I make the popup show up with a `listTrigger` hook. When I click a pair, I expect to have the `currPair` set which depends on `pairList` being populated but it prints as empty.

I should only ever be able to access the handler for changing `currPair` if `pairList` is populated, since it calls `setListTrigger` only after `pairList` is populated in `useEffect()`. It shows it as populated in the `useEffect()` function but it prints empty in `handlePairChange()`. Here is a simplified version of the code. To my understanding It shouldn't even be able to activate `handlePairChange()` unless pairList is populated.

parent.tsx

```
const [listTrigger, setListTrigger] = useState<boolean>(false)
const [currPair, setCurrPair] = useState<PairProps>(intialPair)
const [pairList, setPairList] = useState<PairProps[]>([])
const pairListProps: PairListProps = {trigger: listTrigger, setTrigger: setListTrigger, pairs: pairList}

 //async function that gets data from server
 function handleListTrigger(e: React.MouseEvent) {
    var client: Client = new Client()
    client.getPairList().then(result => {
        var pairs = result[1].pools
        for (let pair of pairs) {
            pair.setPair = handlePairChange
        }
        setPairList(pairs)
    })
}

React.useEffect(() => {
    if(pairList.length !== 0) {
        console.log(pairList)
        setListTrigger(true)
    }
}, [pairList])

function handlePairChange(e: React.MouseEvent) {
    let selectedPairID = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("id")
    console.log(selectedPairID)          //prints correct id
    console.log(pairList)                //prints empty list first time
    for (let pair of pairList) {
        if (pair.id === selectedPairID) {
            console.log("SET CURRENT PAIR TO", pair)
            setCurrPair(pair)
        }
    }
}

return(
    <PairList props={pairListProps}/>
)
```

PairList.tsx

```
export interface PairListProps {
  trigger: boolean
  setTrigger: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
  pairs: PairProps[]
}

export interface PairProps {
  id: string
  tokenA: Token
  tokenB: Token
  exchangeRate: number
  setPair: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLTableRowElement>
}

export interface Token {
  name: string
  amountInPool: number
}

export default function PairList({props}: {props: PairListProps}) {
  if (props.trigger === true) {
    return (
      <div className="pairlist">
        <div className="pairlist-inner">
          <button className="close-btn" onClick={() => props.setTrigger(false)}>
            Close
          </button>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              {props.pairs.map(pair => <Pairs key={pair.id} pair={pair}/>)}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
  else {
    return <></>
  }
}

function Pairs({pair}: {pair: PairProps}) {
  return (
    <tr id={pair.id} onClick={pair.setPair}>
      <button>{pair.tokenA.name}/{pair.tokenB.name}</button>
    </tr>
  )
}
```